# 'class' object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, testing

I'm getting an error "AttributeError: 'Test Employee' object has no attribute 'increment_salary'". Not sure why I'm getting this error because 'increment_salary' is a method, not an attribute and I'm 99% sure I created it correctly. I've searched and the only answers I saw said to check mix of indentation and spaces so I went through and triple checked every indent. It may be wrong here because I am not familiar with how to copy code here but I am sure I did it right in geany.

```
import unittest

class Employee():
    """stores and updates info for each employee"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.salary = salary
    def update_salary(self, new_salary):
        self.salary = new_salary
    def increment_salary(self, increase):
        self.salary += increase

class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        first_name = 'first'
        last_name = 'last'
        pay_name = 100
        self.employee = Employee(first_name, last_name, pay)

    def test_update_salary(self):
        new_salary = 110
        self.employee.update_salary(self.new_salary)
        self.assertEqual(self.new_salary, self.update_salary)

    def test_raise(self):
        increase = 10
        self.employee.increment_salary(increase)
        self.assertEqual(110, self.increment_salary(increase))

unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to call `increment_salary()` *on your `TestEmployee` testcase*:

```
self.assertEqual(110, self.increment_salary(increase))
```

You forgot to call it on `self.employee` instead. The following would not throw the exception:

```
self.assertEqual(110, self.employee.increment_salary(increase))
```

The assertion would fail however because `Employee.increment_salary()` returns `None` always. You want to test what the `salary` attribute is set to in your test:

```
def test_raise(self):
    increase = 10
    self.employee.increment_salary(increase)
    self.assertEqual(110, self.employee.salary)
```

Note that methods are just attributes too; they are *callable* attributes.